# Dialogflow - trainingphrases in intents

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have the following question: should the number of training phrases in intents always be equal across different intents? I'm guessing it's not really required but I'm just trying to gain a deeper understanding of what happens if a certain intent has more training phrases than another intent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no requirement for you to have an exact matching amount of intent phrases.
Usually its recommended to add as many example phrases as possible so that your bot has a wide selection of examples to learn from. If you add very little your bot won't be able to detect user input as valid input for an intent.

Now before you start importing complete dictionaries or webpages with example content, do be careful. More phrases doesn't always mean a better bot. If you have a bot that allows you to ask questions about a company and you start adding example phrases for a cooking FAQ bot, your bot will start responding to cooking questions. So you have to find a good balance between enough phrases and good quality questions that your users will ask.

Having a difference in an amount of phrases has little effect, if you have all your intents available at all times your intents with a lot of examples might get more matches as the bot understands that intent better, but it should still match intents with less examples if the user input is a close match.